# How to exec Vim <Plug> command in function when insert mode?

Tags: vim, neovim

I tried executing  command by putting below

```
fun! DeoEnter()
    if pumvisible()
        if vsnip#available(1)
           " wanna exec function here, like `exe 'normal <Plug>(vsnip-jump-next)'`
        endif

        call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
        if g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res > 0
            return ""
        endif

        return "\<C-y>"
    endif

    return "\n"
endfun
ino <CR> <C-R>=DeoEnter()<CR>
```

, however,  command actually never worked because it is normal mapping, but I wanna accomplish insert mapping.

I looked up document but it's written only normal mode. Is there an any good idea?

Comment: this worked! and this one is what I needed because I tried to exec directly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function is returning keystrokes to execute in insert mode already (through the `<C-r>=...` mechanism), you can do the same for this one.

You can return a double quoted string and use backslashes to escape key sequences (same as you're already doing for `"\<C-y>"` later in that function.)

So you can use `\<Plug>` to enter the `<Plug>` "key". Even if it's not a real key, it behaves the same as one.

Since the `<Plug>(vsnip-jump-next)` needs to be executed in Normal mode, you can use [`<C-o>`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) which allows you to execute a single Normal mode command, from Insert mode, and return to Insert mode when that command completes.

So this line will work over there:

```
return "\<C-o>\<Plug>(vsnip-jump-next)"
```

Putting it all together:

```
fun! DeoEnter()
    if pumvisible()
        if vsnip#available(1)
           return "\<C-o>\<Plug>(vsnip-jump-next)"
        endif

        call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
        if g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res > 0
            return ""
        endif

        return "\<C-y>"
    endif

    return "\r"
endfun
ino <CR> <C-R>=DeoEnter()<CR>
```

I also changed the last line of your function from `return "\n"` to `return "\r"` since that's actually the code that the "Enter" key will produce. (I believe `"\n"` would have worked too, but `"\r"` is more correct in this spot.) You could have also used `return "\<CR>"`, which is equivalent to `"\r"` but more explicit about the fact you're sending the code for the "Enter" key, that's even better.

Comment: The answer is great, and the explaination is great as well. Thank you very much again for your answer.

Comment: @ryuta69 Glad I could help! While we're at it, I'd like to add that you might want to check out the [Vi and Vim StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) website for questions on Vim, you're likely to find great answers for your Vim questions over there!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
ino <CR> :exe "a".DeoEnter()<CR>
```

This way, the result of the `DeoEnter` function will be entered in insert mode

Comment: I fail to see how this is different from `ino <CR> <C-R>=DeoEnter()<CR>`, where the result of the `DeoEnter` function is also entered in insert mode. I mean, they do slightly different things and it's quite possible that it changes behavior enough for an `exe 'normal <Plug>...'` command with a jump to succeed in the latter while it fails in the former. But "will be entered in insert mode" is not a valid explanation for why it works.

Comment: Very true @filbranden, and after testing a bit, I have to admit that I don't understand why my solution worked, while the one in the Original post didn't...

Comment: @Zorzi Sometimes there's a restriction for executing a normal mode command in a function. For example, that's the case with `imap <expr>`, you can't have the function run normal mode commands or execute motions... But I believe that's not the case with `<C-R>=...`, I think that one is totally allowed to do anything it wants to.